# PyQt5 GUI freezes whenever I create big zip files

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, zip

This is the part of code where I create the zipfile. Just change the "path" variable for a real path in your computer and it should work just fine ("path" being the name and path of the new zip file). I can create zip files of small directories without any problem, but if I try to do it with a bigger folder, it just freezes until it's done or it just crashes and shuts down. The zipfile is created though, so the problem is only the GUI freezing and crashing.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
import zipfile
import os

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 180, 381, 101))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.createZipFile)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TEST"))

    def createZipFile(self):    
        directoryname = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()
        abs_src = os.path.abspath(directoryname)
        with zipfile.ZipFile(path,'w') as my_zip2:
            for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(directoryname):
                for filename in filenames:
                    absname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folderName, filename))
                    arcname = absname[len(abs_src) + 1:]
                    my_zip2.write(absname, arcname)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You're running the file creation in the UI thread (the "main" thread), so the UI freezes until the zip file creation is done. Look up how to move computation to a different thread (specifically in qt, that is), there's different possible options available.

Comment: I've googled a bit and found a really great website where QThreads are explained. I've fixed the part where it makes my program crash. Thank you!
[This is the site,](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/concurrent-execution/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/)  if you are wondering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this thanks to GPhilo comment. The answer is basically to use Threads. I linked the page I used to learn how to use them in the comments section.